# JavaFX more Scenes

Tags: user-interface, javafx, scene

Hi Guys i build a GUI and on this GUI is a Button and when I press the Button a second GUI appears, on the second GUI is also a Button and when i press the Button it goes back

GU1

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler <ActionEvent>(){

                public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {

                    try {

                        new GUI2().start(primaryStage);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

My Questions!
Is GUI1 still running when i press the Button?

GUI2

```
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler <ActionEvent>(){

                public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {

                    try {
                        //back to the main menu
                        new GUI1().start(primaryStage);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

When i press the Button, does it go back to the same instance when beginning the program? Or make it a new Instance witch has the same look, and use it more RAM;

How should it works, when i want to open the second GUI in a external Window

Comment: don't understand your question perfectly. Do each of these GUI's have different stage?

Comment: You should really only have one `start(Stage)` method (and one `Application` subclass) per application.

Comment: ok hot do to start the gui without using start();

Answer (score 0):

***When i press the Button, does it go back to the same instance when beginning the program?***

No, a new instance is created based on your code `new GUI2().start(primaryStage);`. Always remember that the`new` keyword **ALWAYS** creates a new object.

***How should it works, when i want to open the second GUI in a external Window?***

There are lots of ways to do this.

**Method 1**

If it happen that you created two applications, both extending the `Application` class, this method should work.

```
public class MultiWindowFX {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getGlobal();

    public static class GUI1 extends Application {
        private final Button buttonShowGUI2;
        private final GUI2 gui2;

        public GUI1() {
            buttonShowGUI2 = new Button("Show GUI 2");
            gui2 = new GUI2();
        }

        public Button getButtonShowGUI2() {
            return buttonShowGUI2;
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            //add an action event on GUI2's buttonShowGUI1 to send front GUI1
                gui2.getButtonShowGUI1().setOnAction(gui2ButtonEvent -> {
                    if (primaryStage.isShowing()) primaryStage.toFront();
                    else primaryStage.show();
                });
            //button with action to show GUI 2
                buttonShowGUI2.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
                    try {
                        if (gui2.getPrimaryStage() == null) gui2.start(new Stage());
                        else gui2.getPrimaryStage().toFront();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                });
            //set scene and its root
                Pane root = new StackPane(buttonShowGUI2);
                Scene stageScene = new Scene(root, 400, 250);
            //set stage
                primaryStage.setScene(stageScene);
                primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
                primaryStage.setTitle("GUI 1");
                primaryStage.show();
        }

        public static void launchApp(String... args) {
            GUI1.launch(args);
        }
    }

    public static class GUI2 extends Application {
        private Stage primaryStage;
        private final Button buttonShowGUI1;

        public GUI2() {
            buttonShowGUI1 = new Button("Show GUI 1");
        }

        public Button getButtonShowGUI1() {
            return buttonShowGUI1;
        }

        public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
            return primaryStage;
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            //get stage reference
                this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
            //set scene and its root
                Pane root = new StackPane(buttonShowGUI1);
                Scene stageScene = new Scene(root, 400, 250);
            //set stage
                primaryStage.setScene(stageScene);
                primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
                primaryStage.setTitle("GUI 2");
                primaryStage.show();
        }

        public static void launchApp(String... args) {
            GUI2.launch(args);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        GUI1.launchApp(args);
    }

}
```

**Method 2**

For me, this is the best approach especially if you want window ownership and modality works.

```
public class GUI1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Show GUI2");
        btn.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            //prepare gui2
                Stage gui2Stage = createGUI2();
            //set window modality and ownership
                gui2Stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                gui2Stage.initOwner(primaryStage);
            //show
                gui2Stage.show();
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("GUI 1");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Stage createGUI2() {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Show GUI1");

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 150);

        Stage gui2Stage = new Stage();
        gui2Stage.setTitle("GUI 2");
        gui2Stage.setScene(scene);

        //add an action event to GUI2's button, which hides GUI2 and refocuses to GUI1
        btn.setOnAction(actionEvent -> gui2Stage.hide());

        return gui2Stage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

...and among other methods. Choose the approach that fits to your requirements.